# Twig Multidimensional Array Variable Not Displaying

Tags: php, symfony, multidimensional-array, twig

The results of a database query populate an array with the following code:

```
if (is_array($result)) {

    $column_count = (int)ceil( count($result) / 2 );
    $row_count = (int)0;
    $column = 1;

    foreach ($result AS $value) {

        $array['concordance'][$column][] = [
            'concordance_word' => $value['word'],
            'book_name'        => $value['book_name'],
            'chapter'          => $value['chapter'],
            'verse'            => $value['verse'],
        ];

        ++$row_count;
        if ( $column_count === $row_count ) { ++$column; }

    }
}
```

An example of $array after the loop populates it is:

```
Array
(
    [concordance] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [concordance_word] => aaron
                            [book_name] => Micah
                            [chapter] => 6
                            [verse] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [concordance_word] => aaron
                            [book_name] => Luke
                            [chapter] => 1
                            [verse] => 5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [concordance_word] => aaron
                            [book_name] => Acts
                            [chapter] => 7
                            [verse] => 40
                        )
```

I am not understanding why the following doesn't access the variable within the Twig view:

```
<h3>{{ document.concordance.1.0.concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>
```

The variable was accessible before I added **$column** to the array as demonstrated in this fashion:

```
<h3>{{ document.concordance.0.concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>
```

I did not make any changes to the controller.  The **dump** command shows the variable being passed.  Is Twig interpreting the **1** as true?  Is there some **|syntax** I must apply for Twig to see this as a multidimensional array variable?

Comment: Have you tried `<h3>{{ document.concordance[1][0].concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>`?

Comment: This results in the error message:  Unexpected token "name" of value "concordance_word" ("end of print statement" expected)

Comment: strange, i can't reproduce your problem, give a last try at this: `<h3>{{ document['concordance'][1][0].concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>`

Comment: You had it right.  I missed the . following [0]  If you will post this as an answer I will up vote you.  Thank you for helping me.

Comment: hi @Ron you are welcome! Sorry i don't understand: is good the first comment or the last one?

Comment: <h3>{{ document.concordance[1][0].concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to an array with the square bracket as follow:

```
<h3>{{ document.concordance[1][0].concordance_word|capitalize }}</h3>
```